# Get card info from idChamp® RS4 BLE RFID device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have **idChamp® RS4 BLE RFID Reader / Writer** device and want to build a ionic app for reading card feature for our company's employees. I have found a `cordova-plugin-ble-central` and try to integrate to the project. All I can get is details data of the peripheral but don't know how to get the data of card (card ID) when tap the card to the peripheral. Does anyone have experience in using this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The card reader should have a Bluetooth API. Ideally you'll get some documentation from the manufacturer that tells you how to use it, but you might have to experiment to figure it out.

Look for a BLE characteristic that has the notification property. If you subscribe to the characteristic notifications, the reader might push data to you when a NFC card is scanned. I'd use an app like LightBlue Explorer or nRF Connect to try and figure out how the BLE service on the hardware works. Once you figure out how the service use cordova-plugin-ble-central in your app to do the same thing.